# Preserve new lines when using the HTML codec in Grails views

Tags: grails, xss

Grails XSS prevention functionality is quite handy, so I enabled it using:

```
grails.views.default.codec = "html"
```

Though, this creates a problem with html `textareas`. If we complete a `textarea` and use Enter to break lines, new lines are saved in the DB, but they are ignored in the view. I could use `<%=%>` and `replaceAll('\n',"<br>")` to fix the line breaks, but HTML code filled in the `textarea` would not be escaped and there would be no XSS prevention!

How would you workaround this problem?

Answer (score 10):

Before rendering your textarea back in GSP, you could

- encode your string as HTML
- convert newline characters to `<br/>`.

This can be achieved by saving the following tag lib to grails-app/taglib:

```
class LinesTagLib { 
  def lines = { attrs, body -> 
    out << attrs['string'].encodeAsHTML().replace('\n', '<br/>\n')
  } 
}
```

As we already applied encodeAsHTML() in the tag, you will have to disable HTML codec when using the tag (using `<%=expression%>` instead of `${expression}`):

```
    <g:lines string="<%=savedTextarea%>" />
```

---

An alternative would be to **write your own codec** for that:

```
class HTMLLinesCodec{ 
  static encode = { str -> 
    str.encodeAsHTML().replace('\n', '<br/>\n')
  } 
}
```

You could then use this codec for GSP files where you want this behaviour by adding directive:

```
<%@ defaultCodec="HTMLLines" %>
```

Comment: Hey Antony, thanks for your reply. I came up with an intermediary solution. What do you say about keeping the enconding as "html" but processing my textareas with: <%= book?.description?.encodeAsHTML().replaceAll('\n','<br>')%>. Do you see any shortcomings to this solution?

Comment: Your solution looks OK. I don't like to have such complicated statements everywhere in my GSPs, that's why I would use a TagLib. If later you decide that you'd like to enclose lines in `<p>string</p>`, you'd only have to change the TagLib. But you're right, if you use that only in one place, then using `<%= book?.description?.encodeAsHTML().replaceAll('\n','<br>')%>` may be the quickest solution.

Comment: I had to add static defaultEncodeAs = 'raw' into LinesTagLib and use it like <g:lines string="${p?.text}" /> (Grails 2.3.6)